# Gridview with horizontal scroll from code behind

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I have an alphabetically sorted list in gridview that scrolls horizontally. Right now the visible gridview has two rows of list items with 5 columns in total. I need to add a functionality where the gridview is scrolled to next 2 columns of list when next button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, You need to get `ScrollViewer` inside the `GridView`. You can use the below method to get it.

```
public ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject element)
{
    if (element is ScrollViewer)
    {
        return (ScrollViewer)element;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i);

        var result = GetScrollViewer(child);
        if (result == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then, In `Button` click event

```
ScrollViewer scrollViewer = GetScrollViewer(gridView);

private void NextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    scrollViewer.ChangeView(scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset + (GridViewItemSize * 2), scrollViewer.VerticalOffset, null, false);
}
```

I have created a helper to do this - [SmoothScrollNavigation Helper](https://github.com/Vijay-Nirmal/SmoothScrollingHelper#smoothscrollnavigation-helper)